# Query two tables linked to same primary key

Tags: sql, ms-access, foreign-keys, primary-key

long time reader first time poster.

I have what looks like a straight forward Access question.

I've an Employee table with these fields;

|EmployeeID|StaffName|Phone|Email|

EmployeeID is a foreign key in two tables - one for logging the status of a generator ie

|LogID|Status|Logged By|

and one for any incidents with the generator

|IncidentID|Description|Raised By|LogID|

I can create a query to link incidents and their log details eg

|IncidentID|Description|Raised By|LogID|Logged By|

This works if I put the EmployeeID number into 'Logged By' and 'Raised By' - if I put the StaffName - as the company wants, it doesn't work because it's selecting two StaffNames from the same primary key.

Any way around this?

Here is the Access code, the part where LoggedBy and RaisedBy are joined to EmployeeID is in bold.

SELECT [2_Incidents].IncidentID, [2_Incidents].Description, [8_Employees].StaffName AS [Raised By], [1_Log].LogID, [8_Employees].StaffName AS [Logged By]

FROM 8_Employees INNER JOIN (2_Incidents INNER JOIN 2_Incidents ON [1_Log].LogID = [2_Incidents].LogID) **ON [8_Employees].EmployeeID = [1_Log].LoggedBy AND [8_Employees].EmployeeID = [2_Incidents].RaisedBy);**

I've gotten around this by creating a copy of the Employees table but this could get awkward if there are more fields linked to Employees in the future (eg Closed By, Verified By etc)

Comment: What do you want exactly? Get the staff name of who logged/raised?

Comment: Edit your question with your current query

Comment: When you [edit] your question please include a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with some sample data from each table, the query you are using, the results you receive, and the results you seek.

Comment: So `LoggedBy` is actually a FK referencing `EmployeeID`? Why would you put a name in a FK field? It should strictly use the PK from the table it is referencing so you avoid this exact problem.

Comment: +1 @Overmind. Relational databases have rules. An autonumber index field joining tables should not be replaced by a user-defined field. Where does company want to see StaffName? If it's in a form, you can easily use a combo box that hides the EmployeeID behind it but shows StaffName. If it's a query output, join the Employees table to the other two but don't show the EmployeeID, only the StaffName.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, useer28470 - yes the names associated with  Logged By and Raised By have to be in a report; Gord Thompson - will do; OverMind - the company wants to show the staff name in queries and reports not the staff Id number this makes things more difficult for me obviously; Parfait - thanks I'll try a combo box

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, the solution is to join to the employee table twice.

In your log details you are doing something like `SELECT * FROM incident JOIN log USING (LogID)`...

You mention "selecting two StaffNames from the same primary key" - I take it that you are attempting to join Employee somehow with Raised By and Logged By.

If you actually join to two copies of employee: `SELECT ... FROM incident JOIN log USING (LogId) JOIN employee ei ON (ei.employeeid = incident.raised_by) JOIN employee el ON (el.employeeid = log.logged_by)` you can reference then the ei.staffname (incident raise by employee) and el.staffname (logged by employee)

PS. Sorry about the non-access syntax, but hopefully you can convert!

Comment: Thanks for that, that's what I'd done as a work around - created a copy of the Employee table, if that's a standard way of doing things then great.

Comment: @Oscar - it isn't a copy of the table here... just referring to the same table twice. In both cases we are using the underlying `employee` table, just referring to one "copy" (reading) as `ei` and the other as `el` so that the query can use that same table twice

Comment: This is the Access syntax for the solution, thanks again.                    SELECT [2_Incidents].IncidentID, [2_Incidents].Description, Alias_RaisedStaff.StaffName AS [Raised By],[1_Log].LogID, Alias_LogStaff.StaffName AS [Logged By], 
FROM 8_Employees AS Alias_RaisedStaff INNER JOIN (8_Employees AS Alias_LogStaff INNER JOIN (2_Incidents INNER JOIN 1_Log ON [2_Incidents].IncidentID = [1_Log].IncidentID) ON Alias_LogStaff.StaffID = [1_Log].LoggedBy) ON Alias_RaisedStaff.StaffID = [2_Incidents].RaisedBy;

Comment: @Oscar Could you accept the answer so that this question gets closed